# Django RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /HomeFeed/comments/slug-1

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I decided to add a "comments" functionality for anyone to post comments on anyone's post. Everything works except one line of code which is giving me the problem.

I receive the following error:

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /HomeFeed/comments/slug-1
> Comment has no post.

The error is directed to the views.py Specifically this line of code:

```
form.instance.post.slug = self.kwargs['slug']
```

How this code can be altered to remove the error?

views.py

```
class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model = 'Comment'
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post.slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url =reverse_lazy('main')
```

urls.py

```
    path('comments/<slug>', AddCommentView.as_view(), name= "add_comment"),
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'body']

        widgets = {
        'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'body' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    chief_title                     = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    body                    = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)
    author                  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug                    = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    date_published          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date published")

     def __str__(self):
       return self.chief_title

     def total_likes(self):
       return self.likes.count()
    
class Comment(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   body = models.TextField()
   date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return '%s - %s' %(self.post.chief_title, self.name)
```

add_comment.html
(this html is for ppl to add their comments)

```
<div class="form-group">
<form  method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<button class="btn btn-secondary">Add Comment</button>
</form>

</div>
```

detail_blog.html
this is for ppl to see the comments

```
{% if not blog_post.comments.all %}
  <p>No comments yet... Add a <a href="{% url 'HomeFeed:add_comment' blog_post.slug %}">comment</a></p>
  {% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'HomeFeed:add_comment' blog_post.slug %}">Add a comment</a>
  <br>
  {% for comment in blog_post.comments.all %}
  <strong>
    {{ comment.name}}
    {{ comment.date_added }}
  </strong>
  <br>
  {{ comment.body }}
  {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `slufField` in Comment's Model. AND you're trying to call `slug` which doesn't exist. First add
`slugField` in `Comment` model. You have to create a new `slugField` for `Comment` Model

Then Try Again

Comment: actually the BlogPost model itself already has the slug field. Do I still need a slugfield in my comments mode? because ultimately the comments is for the blog posts. @Progam

Comment: if I dont use slug field, what should i use to make the whole thing work? haha tbh i followed a tutorial for this code and actually im not sure what this function `def form_valid(self, form):` actually does. My guess is that it helps to link the class to the form that I have created and then validate it with the blog post